# How do I enter a char as input to break out of a loop that is looking for an integer?

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I have this program what reads numbers from an input file, then asks the user to enter a number. The program then reads all numbers in the file and if the number entered is in the file, the program prints back, "Number is in file", if the number entered is not in the file, the program prints back, "Number is not in file." I need to also have it be able to quit the program if the user enters `'q'`, but I am unsure as to how I can do that seeing is that `'q'` is a `char` and the program is looking for an input of an `int`. I did create a variable `char quit = 'q'`, but I'm not sure where to use it, if this is even the right way to start.

```
package classwork7_2;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class ClassWork7_2 {

public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException {

    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

    int[] numbers = fileToArray();
    Arrays.sort(numbers);
    char quit = 'q';


    while (true) {
    System.out.print("Enter a number in the file: ");
    int numb = s.nextInt();
    int i = Arrays.binarySearch(numbers, numb);
    if (i < 0) {
        System.out.print("Number is not in file\n");
    } else {
        System.out.print("Number is in file\n");

    }
}


}

public static int[] fileToArray() throws IOException{

    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] array = new int[7];

    System.out.print("Enter name of file: ");
    String filename = s.nextLine();

    File f = new File(filename);
    Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(f);
    int i = 0;

    while(inputFile.hasNext()){

       array[i] = inputFile.nextInt();
       i++;
    }
        inputFile.close();
        return array;
}
}
```

Comment: Don't use **nextInt()**, instead perhaps use:  `int numb;  String str = s.nextLine(); if (str,charAt(0) == 'q') { break; } if (!str.matches("\\d+") { System.out.println("Invalid Entry!"); continue; } numb = Integer.parseInt(str); // the reset of your code`

Comment: Good approach is to user Scanner.hasNextXXX methods as is described in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the while loop like below:

Here, instead of reading `nextInt`, reading `string` and converting to `int` if it is not `q`

```
while (true) {

        System.out.print("Enter a number in the file: ");
        String ln = s.nextLine();
        if("q".equals(ln)) {
            break;//exiting as user entered "q"
        }
        int numb  = Integer.parseInt(ln);
        int i = Arrays.binarySearch(numbers, numb);
        if (i < 0) {
            System.out.print("Number is not in file\n");
        } else {
            System.out.print("Number is in file\n");

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);    
String userInput = s.next();
int result = Integer.parseInt(userInput);
```

You can take the original number inputs as strings then parse them into an integer and use that result when using your binary search.

Answer (score 0):

Check that if scanner has int or letter 'q':

```
    while (true) {
        System.out.print("Enter a number in the file: ");
        if (s.hasNextInt()) {
            int numb = s.nextInt();
            int i = Arrays.binarySearch(numbers, numb);
            if (i < 0) {
                System.out.print("Number is not in file\n");
            } else {
                System.out.print("Number is in file\n");
            }
        }

        if (s.hasNext("q")) {
            return;
        }
    }
```